# Archiving of old data combined with replication to data warehouse

Tags: mysql

I have a setup that I'm sure is not unheard of (this is MySQL 5.5, but upgrading):

I have a fast growing OLTP database, that I am replicating to an OLAP database. I want to start archiving the fastest growing tables in the OLTP db, but I want the OLAP db to accumulate everything without the archiving part. Is there an easy way to achieve this, or so I have invent my own procedures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following...

- The Master is collecting "raw" data in a "Fact" table.  (I am using Data Wherehouse terminology; I hope the analogy works.)
- The Fact table is not replicated.  But it is `PARTITIONed` by date for efficient archiving.  (We can discuss that separately.)  (If you need 'some' of the Fact table replicated, we can discuss that.)
- On the Master, a few "Summary Tables" ("rollups") are built and maintained.
- The Summary tables *are* replicated.  Querying against these will be much faster than against the Fact table.

DW discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/datawarehouse
Summary Tables:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables
Time Series pruning:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

If you want to dig deeper into these ideas, please provide more details of the application and its data.

Comment: The problem (or one of them) is that some of these tables are absolutely huge - over 500 million rows. Ideally, I'd copy the whole thing to another server, 'the slave', where I can carry out the summarising, then chop down the master tables and in the future send new stuff to the slave, while regularly archiving on the master. But how can I do that without replicating the archiving?

Comment: @j4nd3r53n - For summarization, each of the 500M rows need be touched only once (per summary table).  That is, after initially building the tables (which should have been done long ago), the future summarization is incremental -- only looking at, say, today's rows.  Ditto for partitioning -- it will be costly to set up, but cheap to maintain.

Comment: @j4nd3r53n - And also, the initial setup of a Slave requires copying all the data over.  That is, all of these 'improvements' would have been tolerable at 50M, but will be painful at 500M.  But, properly done, the end result will be a 500M system that is as efficient as a 50M system.

Comment: @j4nd3r53n - And... Reviewing your question:  "Is there an easy way to achieve this" -- No, but I have given you hints of how to achieve them.  "So I have invent my own procedures?" -- Yes; but, again, I have given you hints.  Suggest you get another machine (or VMs) and perfect the actions on a subset of your data.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain - this is very useful for me. I'll accept your answer and think some more about how I proceed. I agree, it is crazy that the OLTP db has been allowed to grow like this; happily not my fault, I'm just trying to find the best way to fix things, and as always, there are Business Requrements, so I can't simply do the right thing.

Comment: @j4nd3r53n - It will take downtime to achieve any of the goals -- a single downtime would be more efficient, but gutsier.  Do practice first.